# NodeJS: Eslint errors on promises

Tags: node.js, promise, eslint

I have this two errors from eslint:

> error  Promise returned in function argument where a void return was
> expected error  Promise executor functions should not be async

They comes from this code:

```
      const promiseFeature = new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      let objectProfile = await this.userFeaturesRepository.findById(id);
      objectProfile = await this.userFeaturesRepository.getProfileObj(myUserFeatures);
      await this.userFeaturesRepository.updateById(id, objectProfile);
      resolve()
    })
    
      const promiseIAM = new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      let objectIAM = await this.userIAMRepository.findById(id);
      objectIAM = await this.userIAMRepository.getIAMObj(myUserFeatures);
      objectIAM.email = objectIAM.email.toLowerCase();
      await this.userIAMRepository.updateById(id, objectIAM);
      resolve()
      })

      await Promise.all([promiseFeature, promiseIAM]);
```

The code works, but I really don´t know who to solve the eslint problem.

Thanks,
In advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it an anti-pattern to use async/await inside of a new Promise() constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036229/is-it-an-anti-pattern-to-use-async-await-inside-of-a-new-promise-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const promiseFeature = new Promise((resolve) => {
    (async() => {
        let objectProfile = await this.userFeaturesRepository.findById(id);
        objectProfile = await this.userFeaturesRepository.getProfileObj(myUserFeatures);
        await this.userFeaturesRepository.updateById(id, objectProfile);
        resolve()
    })();
})
    
const promiseIAM = new Promise((resolve) => {
    (async() => {
        let objectIAM = await this.userIAMRepository.findById(id);
        objectIAM = await this.userIAMRepository.getIAMObj(myUserFeatures);
        objectIAM.email = objectIAM.email.toLowerCase();
        await this.userIAMRepository.updateById(id, objectIAM);
        resolve()
    })();
})

await Promise.all([promiseFeature, promiseIAM]);
```

I guess what's happening here is ESLint is expecting the callback function in your promises to return `void` but they're returning promises since they are `async`.

See the "Return Value" section on [this page from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#return_value).